# Combine two columns into one using CONCAT_WS() in stored procedure using a CONCAT generated string

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I have a stored procedure that does a `select`. The real case is much more complex, but let's say I manage to create a dynamic query using `CONCAT`, so I end up with a valid query string that gets prepared an executed. This example illustrates it:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tmp;;
CREATE PROCEDURE tmp()
BEGIN

SET @sql = '';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
                        ib.visit_id,
                        ib.visit_child
                   FROM
                        infoBase ib
                   GROUP BY
                        visit_id, visit_child');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

I got the expected results with no problem:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╗
║ visit_id ║ visit_child ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╣
║   121340 ║      104280 ║
║   121341 ║      114447 ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Now I'd like to have a third column with the concatenated values of the other two like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ visit_id ║ visit_child ║   combined   ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║   121340 ║      104280 ║ 121340104280 ║
║   121341 ║      114447 ║ 121341114447 ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║ 121485114190 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I add `CONCAT_WS` to accomplish this:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tmp;;
CREATE PROCEDURE tmp()
BEGIN

SET @sql = '';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
                        ib.visit_id,
                        ib.visit_child,
                        CONCAT_WS('', ib.visit_id, ib.visit_child) AS combined
                   FROM
                        infoBase ib
                   GROUP BY
                        visit_id, visit_child');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

But I got an `Error Code: 1064` if I try to do this when I `call myDB.tmp();`
If I run my `SELECT` statement as it is shown above without the store procedure, it does exactly what I need, so I'm pretty sure the problem relies in the nested `CONCAT(CONCAT_WS())` but I don't know how to get what I need.

It's seems easy! Show me your knowledge people!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the single quotes:

The line:

```
'... CONCAT_WS('', ib.visit_id, ib.visit_child) ...'
```

Will be translate as:

```
'... CONCAT_WS(', ib.visit_id, ib.visit_child) ...'
```

You must escape the single quotes:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
                        ib.visit_id,
                        ib.visit_child,
                        CONCAT_WS(\'\', ib.visit_id, ib.visit_child) AS combined
                   FROM
                        infoBase ib
                   GROUP BY
                        visit_id, visit_child');
```

Also you can use:

```
'... CONCAT_WS('''', ...'
```

Comment: SO BASIC =/ I feel ashamed u.u I just didn't notice! I feel so noob now haha http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/36108870.jpg THANKS!